# Console App CSHTML Intellisense and Binding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, console-application

I have a console app without a project reference to any ASP.NET MVC App. Running Visual Studio 2010.

I created a cshtml file to test some template binding. I am not getting IntelliSense in the cshtml and putting "@model MyDataClass" at the beginning of the page is not getting recognized either.

How can get some View functionality in my console app?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you're going to run into a lot more problems - MVC does make use of a number of asp.net constructs (HttpContext, etc) in its view rendering that you're not going to get in a console app. 
It's probably better if you just making a boilerplate MVC project.

Answer (score 3):

Follow instructions in this blog post - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2011/01/20/how-to-get-razor-intellisense-for-model-in-a-class-library-project/

Also, add references to System.Web.Razor.dll and System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll

Answer (score 2):

Try using [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) it allows you to use Razor templating in Console applications.